# Python argparse arguments: issue with passing strings containing hyphens

Tags: python, shell, centos, argparse

I met a strange behaviour with my python code today. I wrote the following small program to illustrate.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--list1", "-l1", nargs='+',  help="liste 1",   metavar="THE_LIST")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.list1:
    print("list1:" + str(args.list1))
```

I ran the code on a first server. I got the expected behaviour (list1 contains a string that includes '-V').

```
$ uname -a
Linux computer 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python  --version
Python 2.7.3
$ cat test.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--list1", "-l1",  help="liste 1", metavar="THE_LIST")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.list1:
    print("list1:" + str(args.list1))
$ python test.py -l1 "abc -V def"
list1:abc -V def
```

I ran it on a second server (Centos 6.6) and got an error. The hyphen seems to be considered as part of an additional argument although the value for -l1 is still enclosed with double quotes... Any idea would be really appreciated...

```
$ uname -a
Linux sacapus 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 11 22:03:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
$ cat test.py 
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--list1", "-l1",  help="liste 1", metavar="THE_LIST")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.list1:
    print("list1:" + str(args.list1))
$ python test.py -l1 "abc -V def"
usage: test.py [-h] [--list1 THE_LIST]
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -V def
```

Comment: Seems to me like this is much more likely to be an issue with your shell/OS than with Python. Added some tags, please feel free to modify if that helps

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.7.6 using bash, ksh, csh, and fish.

Comment: I have to agree with @IanClark; it appears to be a shell issue. I usually run Linux, but happened to be on a Windows machine when I came across this.  I can't replicate the error under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This really shouldn't happen. To figure out what's going on, I would include

```
print(repr(sys.argv))
```

at the beginning of the script, to isolate if the `"abc -V def"` string is really passed as a single argument by the shell.

If it arrives in your program as a single argument blame `argparse`, otherwise your shell is messing up. Either way, this seems like something that should become an entry in CentOS's bug database.

FWIW, I can't reproduce this on Debian Jessie with Python 2.7.9:

```
greek0@orest:/tmp$ python2.7 a.py -l1 "abc -V def"
list1:['abc -V def']
```

Comment: Adding print(repr(sys.argv)) give me ['test.py', '-l1', 'abc', '-V', 'def'] on the centos server.... It may be related to the Python installation on Centos. I got the same error when using the Python 3.3.5 version installed on this server...

Comment: So what does ``print(repr(sys.argv))`` print?

Comment: I got  ['test.py', '-l1', 'abc', '-V', 'def']  on the second server while it gives me the expected output (['test.py', '-l1', 'abc -V def']) on the first.

Comment: Maybe the command is passing through 2 (or more) handlers/shells, one recognizes the `""`, but removes them, while the 2nd passes them to Python as separate strings.

Comment: Investigate what shell (``grep $USERNAME /etc/passwd``) you are using on CentOS. If it's some weird one you might want to switch to ``bash`` or ``zsh``.

Comment: That's it. The python executable was replaced with a shell script that contains: #!/bin/sh LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Softs/users/Python-2.7.9/binaries/lib/ /Softs/users/Python-2.7.9/binaries/bin/python2.7ld (where python2.7ld is the original python executable)

Comment: When running LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Softs/users/Python-2.7.9/binaries/lib/ /Softs/users/Python-2.7.9/binaries/bin/python2.7ld ~/test.py -l1 "abc -V def" I got the expected results. Bravo...

Comment: Also can't replicate under Windows.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger: the simplest was to find out which shell you are using is `ps` (no parameters).